# new template in joomla not working properly

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I've uploaded my new template successfully but on the site it is ging following error
500 - Unable to load renderer class
Error details are as follows:
You may not be able to visit this page because of:

```
an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.
```

Please help me :(

Comment: Please check folder permission

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Joomla that means you have a 404 not a 500 error. Can you provide a link to your site where you are experiencing the error? Also, what template and version of joomla are you using?